# Which is good a camelClass , minus "-" or an undersore "_" for naming CLASS & ID for specially cases

Tags: css

I have been writing CSS from 3yrs. I always naming my `Class` & `ID` in way so easy for others developer to understand it. But now i have a discussion with my follow colleague relating to the naming of `Class` & `ID` when some **special cases** comes.

Here the **special cases** means when some time (It's always happens with everyone) we have no name for `Class` & `ID` then we give names according to it's parent or combination of two name etc. like **.panel_slider** or **.panelSlider** etc.

So, my follow colleague said for this type of special cases it's good to give **underscoe "_"** or **minus "-"** between them. So, easy to write & understand. Like
 **.panel_slider** or **.panel-slider**.

& I am saying it's better to give **camel-case** for this like we are writing in JS. So, it's not taking any additional space of **underscoe "_"** or  **minus "-"**. It's also easy to write & understand.
Like **.panelSlider**.

So, my question is which naming convention is good.

```
a) .panel_slider

b) .panel-slider

c) .panelSlider
```

Comment: The good one is the one you agree on with your team an stick to. This is not constructive.

Comment: In my opinion, typing strings that do not involve chords take noticeably less effort (i.e. avoiding `shift+minus` for an underscore or `shift+s` for uppercase). As for convention, I agree with @Oded; _having_ a convention is good, it does not matter much what it is.

Comment: @Oded thanks for your comment but it's a good thing for a team if we write code with better approach.

Comment: That's my point. It makes 0 difference. The **importanat** thing is to agree on **something**.

Comment: But the fact is, this is asking for _opinions_ and is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: @Oded it's not relating opinions. But to understand what others developer use. Also which approach is good & why.

Comment: Of course it asks for opinions. There is no global standard for naming CSS classes and every developer make their own decisions - this is entirely opinion based.

Comment: @Oded i know that but still we are using some standards & finding a ways for better & optimized css.

Comment: @oded if you think it's an opinion then what your opinion

Comment: I gave my opinion. It. Doesn't. Matter. Choose one and stick with it.

Comment: @Oded  it's not good to say stick with it because who knows which one is correct. If we stick with one thing then we never learn new things.

Comment: All of them are correct. There is no "wrong one".

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Ianzz: when you take a look at [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html), you notice they don't use camelcase or underscores. (e.g. `<div class="text-warning">`) The guys at twitter bootstrap are all about best practices, so it doesn't hurt to follow their notation. But as everybody else said, there isn't really a rule.